# Increase a stored var and use it in the locator

Tags: automated-testing

I would like to use a variable to verify texts. The texts are located with something like:

```
css=tr:nth-child(35) > td:nth-child(2) 

css=tr:nth-child(36) > td:nth-child(2)

css=tr:nth-child(37) > td:nth-child(2)
```

I wanted to use something like

```
store          35            varCounter

verify text    css=tr:nth-child(${varCounter}) > td:nth-child(2)      AAA  
verify text    css=tr:nth-child(${varCounter}+1) > td:nth-child(2)    BBB  
verify text    css=tr:nth-child(${varCounter}+2) > td:nth-child(2)    CCC
```

The first one does what I want, but I can not get the following ones to work. I am using the latest version of Selenium IDE which does not accept StoreEval.

Comment: I am not sure but you could try `${varCounter+1}` instead of `${varCounter}+1`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it does not work.(An invalid or illegal selector was specified)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it :)

```
Command               Target                Value

store                 10                     x  
execute script        return (++${x})        x
type                  (some field)           ${x}*
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like `getEval` `storeEval` , see below:

```
store       25          x

storeEval   ${x}+1      y

type        name=q      ${y}

type        name=${y}   ${x}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in version 3.4.4 that does not work any more...

Comment: I didn't know that it is possible to write Selenese test scripts with version 3 and above. probably 'execute script' is the only way.